# Node.js - do shallow copies from global variables get garbage collected?

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, global-variables, shallow-copy

What if there is a global constant (Object, Array, Map, etc.) defined. And in some method we create a new variable that references this global constant, which is a shallow copy.

Does this shallow copy get garbage collected after exiting the method execution scope? From what I understand global variables do not get garbage collected as they are at the root. And the shallow copy references the same object reference in the heap as the global variable.

I think it does not create a new memory allocation in the Heap since it is not a deep copy, but the Shallow copy would still live on the stack with reference to same memory reference in the heap?

I am wondering if this causes memory leaks?

I am not sure how to see what gets garbage collected through the mark sweep algorithms

Comment: `Does this shallow copy get garbage collected` Yes. `From what I understand global variables do not get garbage collected` But the copy is __not__ stored in a global variable. `And the shallow copy references the same object reference in the heap as the global variable.` A shallow copy is still a copy which doesn't reference the original object.